# No audio output - Asus Zenbook UX3402ZA (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)

Tags: sound, asus

Internal speakers are not producing output in my Asus Zenbook UX3402ZA. Sound works perfectly on Windows 11. I have seen similar posts regarding this issue but could not find any working solution. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: sound settings image]

Kernel: 5.19.0-46-generic

I came to know about one solution [here](https://gist.github.com/lamperez/862763881c0e1c812392b5574727f6ff?permalink_comment_id=4531290#gistcomment-4531290) but it's hard to understand as it involes some deep knowledge about hardware.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. What are the options present when you click the drop down menu under the Output section?

Comment: Follow [this](https://github.com/thor2002ro/asus_zenbook_ux3402za/tree/main) post. It worked for me.

Comment: @shubhampatil This could indeed be a solution. However there is a dualboot so removing the EFI would eliminate its installation of Windows.

Comment: This problem affects all devices featuring the Cirrus CSC3551 chip, which seems to appear in several new models. The bug was analyzed by the kernel team here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215993

The root cause is that the BIOS does not correctly report what settings are needed. Therefore, as long as there is no bugfix to your model's BIOS, or someone reverse-engineers the correct settings for exactly your device (as has been explained for the UM5302 here), there will be no cure. It seems to be all up to ASUS now ...

Answer (score 0):

This problem affects all devices featuring the Cirrus CSC3551 chip, which seems to appear in several new models. The bug was analyzed by the kernel team here: [bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215993](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215993)
The root cause is that the BIOS does not correctly report what settings are needed. Therefore, as long as there is no bugfix to your model's BIOS, or someone reverse-engineers the correct settings for exactly your device (as has been explained for the UM5302 here), there will be no cure. It seems to be all up to ASUS now .